# Wrong output of argv?

Tags: c, string, argv

I'm using gcc in Ubuntu14. Here is my code: (test.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int i=0;
for(i=1; i <argc;i++)
{
    if (argv[i] = "xx") {
       printf("I got you!\n");
    }
printf("%d %s\n",i, argv[i]);   
}
return 0;
}
```

I compile and run this code with:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

`./test aa bb xx`

I expect the output to be

```
1 aa
2 bb
I got you!
3 xx
```

But it comes out with

```
I got you! 
1 xx
I got you! 
2 xx
I got you! 
3 xx
```

even if I use `./test aa bb` the output is

```
I got you! 
1 xx
I got you! 
2 xx
```

I don't know why the output always comes out with "xx", is there anyone give me some hint, please?

Comment: Wrong compilation command. You should use `gcc -Wall -g test.c -o testprog` (you want all warnings `-Wall` and debug info `-g` !!) then **use the debugger** `gdb testprog`

Comment: You can't compare strings in C with the `==` operator (which you don't use btw) but must use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are actually doing here is assigning `"xx"` to `argv[i]` and then branching on the *result* of that assignment. This is because the  `=` operator is for assignment. When *testing* (i.e. *comparing*) a value you need to use the operator for equality, which is `==`.

Also, strings cannot be compared in this manner anyway as they are not a primary data type as they are in some other languages. If you tried `if (argv[i] == "xx")` you would be comparing the address of the first character of each of the strings, which would still be wrong!

To solve this we can use the `strcmp()` function which compares the contents of two strings and returns a non-zero result if the strings are different. The `strcmp()` function is made available by the `string.h` header file.

So to achieve your intended result add `#include <string.h>` at the top of your file and use `if (strcmp(argv[i], "xx") == 0)`.

See [this Tutorials Point page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) for more information on `strcmp()`

Comment: @link5555 You're welcome. FYI if you're new to SO: if an answer (doesn't need to be mine) solves your problem you should click the tick mark beside it so that the question appears as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with `if (argv[i] = "xx")`:

1. You're using the assignment operator and it makes `argv[i]` point to the string literal `"xx"`. And since the address of the string literal will always be non-`NULL`, the condition is always true.

   You probably wanted to use the equality operator `==`. But then it still won't work. See point no 2 below.
2. Using `==`, you check if `argv[i][0]`'s memory location is the same as that of the first character of `"xx"` (This happens due to array "decay", Google it). This is not what you want.

   You want to compare the *contents* of `argv[i]` with the string literal. So, use [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) from `string.h`:

   ```
   if (strcmp(argv[i], "xx") == 0)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
if (argv[i] = "xx") {
           ^^^
```

the address of the first character of the string literal `"xx"` is assigned to the pointer `argv[i]`. As the value of the address is not equal to 0 then this expression yields always true.

However if you will write

```
if (argv[i] == "xx") {
            ^^
```

then there will be compared two addresses: the address of the corresponding user-supplied parameter and the address of the string literal (addresses of their first characters). As result the expression will yield always false.

What you need is to compare strings pointed to by these pointers. So you should write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( ++i < argc )
    {
        if ( strcmp( argv[i], "xx" ) == 0 ) 
        {
            printf( "I got you!\n" );
        }

        printf( "%d %s\n", i, argv[i] );   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_the expression will yield always false_" -- Isn't it possible for it to be true because of string pooling? That is, assuming `argv[i]` points to `"xx"`

Comment: @CoolGuy It is impossible because string literals are allocated at compile time have static storage duration and are non-modifiable while user supplied parameters are allocated at run-time and modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

a) because = does no comparison but an assignment

b)you gotta use a string comparison function (== wouldn't work either for it)